# Get Data and save it as JSON in AWS Storage by Lambda Function

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I want to know what services I should use.

[at morning/everyday] - getting data(array of api links, 20-30 items) and saving it as json array in some storage. I want to know where I can save this json data, to make CRUD operations by Lambda Functions with it later?

Comment: you can utilize DynamoDB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the limited description, here's an outline of one way to solve it:

1. DynamoDB table for persistent storage of JSON objects.
2. Lambda function that accepts a list of URLs as input, invokes those APIs, persists results to DynamoDB.
3. CloudWatch Events to schedule the Lambda to run each morning.
4. Lambda function writes a message to SNS indicating success/failure of the API invocations.
5. Subscribe by email to the SNS topic to see results.

Make sure the Lambda function timeout is long enough to invoke all the URLs and persist the results. Or move to a slightly more complex solution where you enqueue the URLs to SQS and have SQS trigger the Lambda function with a batch of 5-10 URLs at a time.

Comment: DynamoDB is best option. Thanks!